# Calculus 2: Inverse Trig Functions

Tags: calculus, inverse

I'm stuck on the following problem:

I'm looking at the solution provided by the teacher but I think it might be wrong?  Please let me know if the solution is wrong ... and if so where...

I personally think it should be $$\frac{7}{5}\sin^{-1}(\frac{7x}{5})$$ ....

[image]

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Regarding your statement of

> I personally think it should be 7/5(sin^-1(7x/5) ....

note that by the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{d\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{7x}{5}\right)\right)}{dx} & = \frac{d\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{7x}{5}\right)\right)}{d\left(\frac{7x}{5}\right)}\frac{d{\left(\frac{7x}{5}\right)}}{dx} \\
& = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{7x}{5}\right)^2}}\right)\left(\frac{7}{5}\right) \\
& = \frac{7}{5\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{7x}{5}\right)^2}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Answer (score 3):

The answer is correct except that a minus sign is missing here:
$$u=25-49x^2 \implies du=\color{red}{-98}dx$$

For the arcsin the integral is correctly evaluated:
$$I=\int \dfrac {d\left(\dfrac 75 x\right)}{\sqrt {1-\left(\dfrac 75 x \right)^2}}=\arcsin \left(\dfrac 75 x\right)$$
Just substitute $u=\dfrac 75 x \implies du=\dfrac 75 dx$
$$I=\int \dfrac {du}{\sqrt {1-u^2}}=\arcsin u=\arcsin\left(\dfrac 75 x\right)$$